# Returning query results within rules (when clause of drl file) in drools

Tags: drools

I need help in retrieving query results within when clause of `drl` file in drools.

Example rule file having query:

```
query getUsersForCard (Long ipCardNumber)
    $listOfUsers : UsersList()
    $listOfUserCards : User(cardNumber == ipCardNumber, $cardNum : cardNumber) from $listOfUsers.user_list
end

rule "matchUser" 
when
    getUsersForCard("4444333322221112L";)
then
    System.out.println( "$$$card number in VisaMessage matched with card number in UsersList$$$" );
end
```

How to obtain `$cardNum` after`getUsersForCard` query call so that then clause gets printed? I don't want to retrieve `$cardNum` in Java code from Working Memory but rather should be able to do it within the `drl` file itself.

Help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Going back to the original question: "Can query results be accessed from the LHS of a rule?", the answer is: "Yes, using unification ([Sections 8.8.3.3.6 and 8.9](http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/6.3.0.Final/drools-docs/html_single/))".

A query in Drools can have input and output parameters. Input parameters are those that have a value (are bound) when the query is invoked. Those parameters that don't have a value (unbound) are considered output parameters.

The first thing to do is to rewrite your query using unification:

```
query getUsersForCard (Long ipCardNumber, Long $cardNum)
    $listOfUsers : UsersList()
    $listOfUserCards : User(
        cardNumber == ipCardNumber,
        $cardNum := cardNumber
    ) from $listOfUsers.user_list
end
```

The important thing to notice is the **:=** (unification) sign being used. This operator is basically saying: "If the variable has a value, then I'll act as an **==** operator. Otherwise I'll act as a variable binding.

When invoking your query from a rule, you need to make sure you don't provide any value for the second parameter in the query. Given that you are already using positional arguments, that's easy to do:

```
rule "matchUser" 
when
    getUsersForCard("4444333322221112L", $cardNum;)
then
    System.out.println( "$$$card number in VisaMessage matched with card number in UsersList$$$: "+$cardNum );
```

end

When the query is invoked, `$cardNum` will not have a value and it will set by the query because of the unification mechanism.

Hope it helps,

Comment: Note that in this particular case, your are binding `$cardNum` in the query to the same attribute you are adding the `==` constraint! From a logical perspective, this makes no sense at all.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot retrieve query results within the when clause the way I think you think it can be done. But there is no need to do so, simply write the rule as

```
rule "match card number"
when
    $listOfUsers: UsersList()
    $user: User(cardNumber == "4444333322221112L") from $listOfUsers
then ... end
```

Assuming the text of the println indicates what you really want to do, you might use

```
rule "match card number"
when
    VisaMessage( $cardNo: cardNumber )
    $listOfUsers: UsersList()
    $user: User(cardNumber == $cardNo) from $listOfUsers
then ... end
```

Comment: Thanks laune for your quick reply. I actually tried the approach you suggested. But my requirement is to fire the query from the when condition of rule file (drl) and capture the $cardNum from the query to set it to an output fact object in the then clause. I am being asked if this is possible! As per your say, I understand that you mean query results can only be pulled out from the Working Memory by writing the Java code. I did that! But can you pl. confirm once again if we can't handle it within the rule file (drl) itself.

Comment: It is possible to call a query in left hand side code but not the query you have shown. Also, if you already have the cardNum you can check that it is among the ones in the UsersList - you cannot "capture" it from that list because you already have it! It doesn't make sense to call the query with a literal ("4444333322221112L"). If you want to continue this discussion, edit your question to reflect the actual situation more accurately.

Comment: Also, you can call a query on the right hand side of a rule since this is written using Java code. But this doesn't make any sense either: you can achieve the same thing *much more easily* using other Drools techniques.

Comment: Finally: a requirement to achieve a result in a way that isn't "best practice" without providing a sound reason for doing so merely shows that the originator of that requirement hasn't understood Drools, or programming using rules. Is there a reason for demanding a query?

Comment: Appreciate greatly for your replies Laune! The requirement is to evaluate performance (execution times taken) for validating a user card number against a list of user card numbers. So, as part of this requirement, I have considered parsing a single card number as part of VisaMessage fact & a list of card numbers as part of UsersList fact. Using query, I have the execution time noted as **0.35 secs**  The above is for 1 card number Vs 1 million card numbers validation with matching card inserted in VisaMessage fact at the end (worst case consideration)

Comment: So, Laune, you convey that best practice to handle query result(s) is in the Java code by retrieving from the QueryResults class as you said above that having a query in the RHS of rule doesn't make sense as I understand that the very nature of Drools query is without the RHS declaration.  Am I missing anything here Laune? Pl. advise in view of the requirement stated above.  Also, one last question Laune. If I trigger the query from the LHS as posted in the code snippet in the question, it doesn't make any sense in calling fireAllRules() method, right? As retrieving results can b by Query Name

Comment: So if you want to have some performance figures you have to create a situation that corresponds to the intended use case. I doubt very much that using a query in LHS side code is that use case (for reasons described in previous comments). According to our comment "Appreciate...", 2nd sentence, you need to evaluate the evaluation of a card no. matching one out of a list of user cards. I hope that you don't plan to do this by using a query. What is best depends on *the details of the use case*: is this done repeatedly for different card nos? For what  else do you use rules? And more...